# Ordered list using react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown, react-markdown

I am trying to render an ordered list using `react-markdown`:

```
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'

const MyComponent = () => {
    const markdown = `<ol><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li></ol>`;
    return (
       <ReactMarkdown children={markdown} remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]} />
    );
}
```

The output is the string `<ol><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li></ol>`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [react-markdown docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown) (Appendix A), in order to render raw HTML within a `ReactMarkdown` component you will need the `rehypeRaw` plugin.

```
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import rehypeRaw from "rehype-raw";

const markdown = `<ol><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li><li>Item 3</li></ol>`;

const RootElement = () => {
  return <ReactMarkdown rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]} children={markdown} />;
};
```

I've prepared a [simple CodePen](https://codepen.io/luco5826/pen/gOxBoNL) too